# What are the consequences of RAM speed to high on a Proliant DL385 G7?

Tags: performance, memory, hardware, hp-proliant

Rendering the 3D model of an optical lens or mirror with openSCAD can require huge amount of RAM, and for this use, I have maxed the RAM on a Proliant DL385 G7 but the RAMs I got were PC-14900: 1866MHz instead of the required PC-10600: 1333MHz).

Should it be a cause for a real problem or is it just the speed reporting that might be hindered ? The memory test at boot after the change reported no problem, but iLO claims that my RAM run at 9MHz...

What would be a good test for the effective speed ?

[image].

Answer (score 0):

It'll just run it at it's max supported speed and no higher, probably 1333, at which point the DIMMs won't care, they're JDAC-spec so I'm sure will happily sit there running slowly forever.

That said that's an OLD server, and deeply power-hungry for its capabilities - given the batch nature of your application and comparatively small requirements (because it clearly works on that server) it'd probably be an ideal candidate to run in some form of public cloud.

Comment: That's what I expected, but I'd like to make sure it's really what is happening, because The iLO report is making me worry and some of the output log (echo commands) seems really slow, but there might be other reasons. For the rest, I know it's power hungry, but I'm only using it for very occasional purposes, when I need a huge ram.